# What is the correct preposition after “rights”?

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number

This question came up for me within the context of intellectual property rights in a film grant competition.

When “right” is singular, the correct preposition is “to,” such as in the *right to* free speech.

When “rights” is plural, it’s less clear to me.

Of the following examples, which is correct? If both are technically correct, do they have slightly different meanings?

> Who would retain the intellectual property rights **to** the work?

or

> Who would retain the intellectual property rights **for** the work?

As a bonus, I am almost certain the below is *not* correct under any circumstance, but will place it here for good measure, in case I’m wrong:

> Who would retain the intellectual property rights **on** the work?

Comment: In this sense "rights to" is more idiomatic in the US.  I would not say that any of the three is "wrong", though.

Comment: @HotLicks Make that an answer! Do you think they imply different meanings, however slight?

Comment: I can't see a major difference.  The latter two are apt to be misinterpreted in certain contexts, however.

Comment: @HotLicks I still encourage you to write these thoughts up as an answer. How do you think they’d be misinterpreted? Or is it more that they’d just sound awkward?

Comment: I have also seen "rights in the work" fairly often.

Comment: @JamesRandom Really? I have never. Is that a particular localization of English?

Comment: An example (just one of the first Google results): "*For example, co-authors of a book would both have intellectual property rights in the work*" https://www.rochelegal.co.uk/news/your-creative-legacy-who-will-get-your-intellectual-property-when-you-die/ (Google said there were 2 million hits, but we know that is meaningless!)

Answer (score 3):

Any of the 3 prepositions can be used after the word "rights".

In this case, decide on the context. "...*for* the work" sounds best in my opinion. A person would like recognition *for* (not *to* or *on*) work that was done.

In my opinion "to" would be better suited for a sentence like: "John inherited the rights to his uncle's mansion." (Just as he would like keys *to* (not *for* or *on*) the mansion's door). But I would use "for" in the sentence: "John obtained the creative rights for the book he wrote." (Just as he would like to get a publisher for (not *to* or *on*) his book).

I can't think of any use cases for "on", but it would certainly be less common than the other two.

Defining a rule for this, would be too complex. But one should judge by the context. Consider common implications of the preposition in question.

Hope that helps :).

Comment: Definitely helpful. Thanks! Also posted within 5 seconds of @HotLicks, who agrees any are valid but prefers _to_ while you prefer _for_. I find that interesting—and I still suspect they might imply _slightly_ different meanings though know how. I’m curious if anyone in a legal context would interpret them differently.

Comment: *Rights* is used instead of *right* because the original owner frequently wants to break them up for assignment or sale. For example, the right to translate a book and sell it in a different country might be sold separately from the movie rights. So the sentences built around this concept can often become quite complex, bringing in more than one preposition.

Answer (score 3):

In this sense "rights to" is more idiomatic in the US. I would not say that any of the three is "wrong", though -- I can't see a major difference between them.

At worst, the latter two are apt to be misinterpreted in certain contexts. For instance, "in the works" can mean "under development", so "Joe Blow has intellectual property rights in the works" might be interpreted to mean he's somehow developing them or has a lawyer working to obtain them.

Comment: Great point about “in.” Is there another expression that “for” could be confused with? I cannot think of one.